# Configuring the PAN network on bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I wanted to establish a TCP connection between my java-supported Nokia X2-01 and my Ubuntu Desktop. I read several guides but they seem to be pretty old (Ubuntu ~8,9). Mainly the issue is with my bluetooth network not providing a DHCP server for my phone, so it does not get assigned an IP address.

The older methods involve fiddling with the pand config files. I was wondering if there is a better GUI based, or a simpler CLI way to assign an IP address to my phone on connection.

`ifconfig` gives the following output :

```
bnep0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:2b:f9:68:7c  
          inet addr:10.0.66.3  Bcast:10.0.66.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:2bff:fef9:687c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:760 (760.0 B)  TX bytes:8692 (8.6 KB)
```

But when I try to open 10.0.66.3 on my cell phone, it does not connect.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so this question is coming up to a year old but I'll answer it anyway!

You need to set up a dhcp server like you've said, but there's no graphical way to do it, as far as I'm aware. Fortunately it's relatively painless, but appears to be a little daunting.

The first thing to do is install the dhcp server. `sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server` should achieve this.

Once it's installed, you need to set what interfaces it should run on. To do this, you need to edit the `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` file on 12.04 (pre-12.04 the file may be called `dhcp3-server`). To do this, run `sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`. It should have a line like this:

`INTERFACES=""`

change it to match your interface name, in your case `bnep0`:

`INTERFACES="bnep0"`

use `CTRL+O` (thats o as in onion, not 0 as in 10) to save the file and `CTRL+Q` to quit

next you need to set up the DHCP server. To do this, first remove the template configuration:

`sudo rm /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

then create a new config and enter this:

(open with `sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`)

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;


subnet 10.0.66.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
 range 10.0.66.4 10.0.66.14
}
```

(matches your settings)

after that, (re)start the dhcp server with

`sudo service start isc-dhcp-server`.

if it complains it's already running, try

`sudo service restart isc-dhcp-server`

and that should be it :D